# Flutter Daemon Terminated

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, daemon, android-studio-3.0

When I open android studio,  after two minutes  the Flutter device selection will disappear and a message pop-up said "Flutter daemon terminated"
I already tried restarting Android studio, but it didn't work

The Emulator works on its own
but the major issue is the I can not run my code, because the Flutter device selection keeps on disappearing.
I tried to also use VS code , but it had the same issue that the "Flutter Daemon Terminated"